# Ag-grid highlight cell logic not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I created an editable grid using **ag-grid** and I need to highlight the cells that were changed. I added the following code:

```
    (cellValueChanged)="onDemandsCellValueChanged($event)"
```

And the method:

```
    onDemandsCellValueChanged(params): void {
    if (params.oldValue === params.newValue) {
      return;
    }

    params.data.modified = true; // add modified property so it can be filtered on save

    const column = params.column.colDef.field;
    params.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': '#e1f9e8' }; // highlight modified cells
    params.api.refreshCells({
      force: true,
      columns: [column],
      rowNodes: [params.node],
    });
  }
```

The cell is highlighted but when I scroll up and down all the cell from that column are highlighted.

You can check the behavior on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-demo-cmasgw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Also if you have a better way of doing this I'm open to new solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your problem You can achieve what you want like this - you should use `cellStyle` in your column definition as showing in [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/#cell-style) and for this code is below

```
cellStyle: params => {
      if (
        params.data["modifiedRow" +
                     params.node.rowIndex +"andCellKey"+ 
                     params.column.colDef.field]
      ) {
        return { backgroundColor: "#e1f9e8" };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
```

and after that in this function `onDemandsCellValueChanged` please add and modify this property `modified` as true and change your function like this as shown below

```
onDemandsCellValueChanged(params): void {
    if (params.oldValue === params.newValue) {
      return;
    }
    const column = params.column.colDef.field;
    params.data["modifiedRow" + params.rowIndex + "andCellKey" + column] = true;
    params.api.refreshCells({
      force: true,
      columns: [column],
      rowNodes: [params.node]
    });
  }
```

Now it should work even when you scroll. Here is complete [working Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-demo-j2gcux?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This fixed the up and down scrolling problem. But now it happens when I scroll to the right or left. You can check this behavior on your stackblitz example. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @NicuVlad, I have updated the example now you can try upper working Example on stackblitz and if you find this answer helpful please accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks! This was the best solution I could find for highlighting modified cells. However, it breaks down when deleting rows. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: There is no need to add the row number to the modified key because params.data contains only data of the modified row. Omitting the row number makes this also work when rows are deleted (otherwise, highlighting breaks due to changing row numbers).